# Scala: From nested case class to flatten case class

Tags: scala

The question is:

**How to build a general function that can take any case class that is composed of other case classes and flatten that into one case class with all values from each case class in the composed case class?**

For example, I would like to convert a **nested case class** like this:

```
case class A(first: String, second: String)
case class B(value: String)

case class Nested(a: A, b: B)
```

to a **flatten case class** like this:

```
case class Flatten(aFirst: String, aSecond: String, bValue: String)
```

But I would like to **avoid to build my own constructor** (or create a function manually) like this:

```
object Flatten {

  def apply(nested: Nested): Flatten = {
    Flatten(nested.a.first, nested.a.second, nested.b.value)
  }
}
```

*Note: in real use case, case classes are more complex and I would like to use the method several times on different case classes.*

Comment: You can create a `Flatten` constructor method in `Nested` class. But its almost the same.

Comment: You'll need to write a function `somewhere` to take a Nested and return a Flatten. Why don't you want this to live in Flatten's apply? Where would you like it instead? How do you envision calling this conversion?

Comment: you should take a look into scala-reflection library.

Comment: @Metropolis: I am looking for something more automatic (in real use case I have lot of element in my nested case class). `Apply` or other function to do that manually is not the purpose of the question. Maybe there is some library to flatten case class ? One source of inspiration is https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/transforms/flatten.html#flatten

Comment: So your question is: how to build a general function that can take any case class that is composed of other case classes and flatten that into one case class with all values from each case class in the composed case class? If so, I think it would help to clarify your question. As it reads now, its seems like you're talking about doing this only once.

Comment: Ok, I thoight I was clear, I edit my question

Comment: looks like a job for Shapeless

Answer (score 2):

You can play with reflections api assuming that the target case class field names have a predefined format. Take a look at the example

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

class Converter(any: Any) {
  private val rm = runtimeMirror(any.getClass.getClassLoader)

  private def nameToPath(name: String, pathElem: String = "", pathElems: List[String] = List()): List[String] =
    if (name.isEmpty) pathElems :+ pathElem.toLowerCase()
    else if (name.head.isUpper) nameToPath(name.tail, name.head.toString, pathElems :+ pathElem)
    else nameToPath(name.tail, pathElem + name.head, pathElems)

  private def valueByPath(v: Any, pathElems: List[String]): Any =
    if (pathElems.isEmpty) v
    else {
      val im = rm.reflect(v)
      val fieldName = TermName(pathElems.head)
      val field = im.symbol.info.member(fieldName).asTerm
      val value = im.reflectField(field).get
      valueByPath(value, pathElems.tail)
    }

  def convertTo[T: TypeTag]: T = {
    val target = typeOf[T]
    val fieldNames = target.decls.sorted.collect {
      case m: MethodSymbol if m.isCaseAccessor => m
    }

    val paths = fieldNames.map(s => nameToPath(s.name.toString))
    val values = paths.map(valueByPath(any, _))

    val constructorSymbol = target.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR)

    val defaultConstructor = constructorSymbol match {
      case cs: MethodSymbol => cs
      case ts: TermSymbol =>
        ts.alternatives.collectFirst {
          case ms: MethodSymbol if ms.isPrimaryConstructor => ms
        }.get
    }

    val cs = target.typeSymbol.asClass
    val cm = rm.reflectClass(cs)
    val constructor = cm.reflectConstructor(defaultConstructor)
    constructor(values: _*).asInstanceOf[T]
  }
}

implicit class AnyOps(any: Any) {
  def to[T: TypeTag]: T = new Converter(any).convertTo[T]
}
```

using

```
val a = A("1", "2")
val b = B("3")
val n = Nested(a, b)

val r = n.to[Flatten]
```

output

```
r: Flatten = Flatten(1,2,3)
```

Comment: I got an error `scala.ScalaReflectionException: class Flatten is an inner class, use reflectClass on an InstanceMirror to obtain its ClassMirror`. Maybe I did something wrong ?

Comment: Seems you defined your Flatten class inside another class

Comment: Thanks, I will try it

Comment: it works well but I have to write each field for the flatten case class. I would like something more automatic that will automatically create the case class Flatten for example. I don't really know if it's possible...